# Is it possible to mask a <div>, or to overlay text with a masked image?

Tags: css, image

I'm almost sure this is not possible, but just wanted to ask if I'm correct.

I have a  container with a solid background color and with text in it. This  floats over an image. Currently, the text color is black, but what I'd like to have is that the text becomes transparent, such that I can see through the s background color and onto the image behind it. I know this sounds impossible, so I thought that I could achieve the same effect if I overlay the text with the same image but mask it somehow such that only the parts covering the text are visible.

I hope it is clear what I mean. I would be happy if someone had an idea how I could do this, and if it can't be done, point me to some evidence why it can't be done :)

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an property in for webkit based browsers called `-webkit-background-clip: text`. Write like this:

```
p{
    background-image:;
    background:  url(http://2.bp.blogspot.com/-NSwhl6hv41Y/Th5EIJL_zZI/AAAAAAAAFc4/UGUNfb--tGc/s1600/vector_wallpaper_by_seppoftw.jpg);
    -webkit-background-clip: text; 
    -webkit-text-fill-color: transparent;
    font-size:100px;
    margin:40px;
}​
```

Check this http://jsfiddle.net/yvYG8/

Read this for  more http://trentwalton.com/2011/05/19/mask-image-text/

Comment: The link is right, but I'd suggest to use the other option explained there: `mask-image`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Looks nice, too bad this won't work in all browsers. But good to know that it can be done :)